# Selenium Chrome Node doesn't resolve urls on kubernetes with Scalatest

Tags: scala, google-chrome, kubernetes, scalatest

I'm using Scalatest and Selenium for testing. The Selenium Hub and the Chrome node are running on 2 Kubernetes Pods.
I have the webservice I need to test on another pod. It has an internal address http://myui.dev/. It's not accessible from outside.
The test continue to fail. When the webdriver is trying to reaching the internal url the page is getting is the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT page on Chrome.

I tried to:

- connect from scalatest to another url (www.google.co.uk) and it
  **worked**.
- I've tried to access the the selenium hub container and I can curl either **google** or my **internal** url.
- I've accessed the pod with the
  chrome node and curl the url. It **worked** as well.

So, my best guess it's that for some reason it's not taking or overriding the /etc/resolv.conf inside the container.

Any idea how to fix this?

Some configuration that could be helpful:

- scalatest version: 3.0.5
- selenium-java version: 3.12.0
- Selenium Hub image: selenium/hub:latest
- Selenium Chrome node image:
  selenium/node-chrome:latest

The pod configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
     service: selenium-chrome
  name: selenium-chrome
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: selenium-chrome
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: HUB_HOST
          value: selenium-hub
        - name: NODE_MAX_INSTANCES
          value: "10"
        - name: NODE_MAX_SESSION
          value: "10"                
        image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
        name: selenium-chrome
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /dev/shm
              name: extended-mem
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        # extended memory for the browser
        - name: extended-mem
          hostPath:
            path: /dev/shm
status: {}
```

**UPDATE [25/06/2018]:**
I've figure it out. Apparently wasn't a dns problem. As Matthew suggested it's not a DNS problem. Indeed when I run:

```
kubectl run selenium-hub --image selenium/hub --port 4444
kubectl expose deployment selenium-hub --type=NodePort
kubectl run selenium-node-chrome --image selenium/node-chrome --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub" --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444"
```

it works.

Comment: _ ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT_ ... _overriding the /etc/resolv.conf inside the container_ -- I wouldn't expect those two things to have any relationship unless you are trying to do DNS trickery to override `myui.dev` from whatever it is currently resolving to; what is the output of the working `curl` command from inside the container?

Comment: The output it's the webservice page.

Comment: Check whether you are able to do things from host wherever you are deploying

Comment: _The output it's the webservice page_ haha, you're a funny guy. I mean `curl -vo /dev/null http://whatever` -- I don't care about the page content, I care about the IP address, proxy usage, headers, timeouts, whatever